# How do you change the controller text in an ASP.NET MVC URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I was recently asked to modify a small asp.net mvc application such that the controler name in the urls contained dashes. For example, where I created a controller named ContactUs with a View named Index and Sent the urls would be http://example.com/ContactUs and http://example.com/ContactUs/Sent. The person who asked me to make the change wants the urls to be http://example/contact-us and http://example.com/contact-us/sent.

I don't believe that I can change the name of the controller because a '-' would be an illegal character in a class name.

I was looking for an attribute that I could apply to the controller class that would let me specify the string the controller would use int the url, but I haven't found one yet.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: setting the routing rules worked and was the easiest. I was hoping for something that I could put in the controller class so that the setting would be close to the controller and not located in a different place where another developer might not notice it. Also this leaves the old route /ContactUs/ still working. might see if I can get the iis7 url rewriter to do a perm redirect.

Thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: Happy to help.  Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply change the URL used in the route itself to point to the existing controller.  In your Global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Contact Us",
  "contact-us/{action}/",
  new { controller = "ContactUs", action = "Default" }
);
```

Comment: Looks good.  This (and Richard's answer) is probably a good solution.

Comment: Not precisely the "way" Zack envisioned the solution, but a more valid one, I believe.  This way, there's no need to bend controller names for the sole purpose of friendly URLs.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can change the display name of a controller. In the beta, the controller was created using route data "controller" with a "Controller" suffix. This may have changed in RC/RTM, but I'm not sure.

If you create a custom route of "contact-us/{action}" and specify a default value: `new { controller = "ContactUs" }` you should get the result you are after.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure routing. In your `Global.asax`, do the following:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  ...
  routes.MapRoute(
    "route-name", "contact-us/{action}", // specify a propriate route name...
    new { controller = "ContactUs", action = "Index" }
  );
  ...
```

As noted by Richard Szalay, the `sent` action does not need to be specified. If the url misses the `.../sent` part, it will default to the `Index` action.

Note that the order of the routes matter when you add routes to the `RouteCollection`. The first matched route will be selected, and the rest will be ignored.

Comment: your second route is not required if you append /{action} to the path of the first.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ASP.NET MVC developers covers what Iconic is talking about.  This was something I was looking at today in fact over at [haacked](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/04/areas-in-aspnetmvc.aspx).  It's worth checking out for custom routes in your MVC architecture.

*EDIT*: Ah I see, you could use custom routes but that's probably not the best solution in this case.  Unless there's a way of dealing with the `{controller}` before mapping it? If that were possible then you could replace all "-" characters.

Comment: I am not sure if that article is related to what he's asking.

Comment: Cheers - you can tell it's the end of the day, I'm not reading things properly!